# NuGet Package Manager not showing Installed Packages

Tags: .net, nuget

We have a team of devs. All have NuGet installed. We are all using TFS. One team member adds a NuGet package and checks in. The other team members all get the associated assemblies and NuGet packages.config fine. However, when they go to "Manage NuGet Packages" the "Installed Packages" does not show the package added by other team members. It shows fine for the person that added the package initially.

Is this expected behavior? Are we doing something wrong?

Thanks

Comment: You checked the answer to this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6182526/why-doesnt-installed-packages-show-the-package-i-just-installed .  I tried browsing the NuGet source, but it is a rats nest of interfaces and the service locator pattern =P

Comment: Thanks for the link but that file was already in all users solutions fine, so assume that isn't the answer.

Comment: I ran across this, http://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/1211, not sure if it's useful

Answer (score 3):

One issue i have found is that the packages are not considered part of the solution and get saved at the solution level (this is in a packages folder). You may need to do a check-in on the solution folder (in source control explorer) to check in the packages that nuget downloads so that others get both the references and the packages.

Comment: The "packages" folder that is at the same level as the solution file was checked in along with all files within. Do you get the same behavior that I am seeing on your project? Thanks

Comment: The assemblies should be at the root directory of the TFS repository indeed.